# Prove that $f$ must have an inflection point at $0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives, proof-writing, proof-explanation

> Suppose $f$ is a function such that $f'(x)>0$ $\forall x\not=0$ and $f'(0)=0$. Also, $f''$ is a continuous $\text{one to one}$ function on some open interval containing $0$. Prove that $f$ must have an inflection point at $0$.

**Pf:**

Let a,b be arbitrary values in the open interval containing $0$ such that $a<0<b$

Since $f''$ is a continuous $1-1$ on [a,b], then either $f'''>0$ $\forall x \in [a,b]$ or $f'''<0$ $\forall x \in [a,b]$. So, -$f''
$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and $f''$ is differentiable on $(a,b)$

By the mean value theorem, there exists $c$ with, $a<c<b$ such that $$f''(c)=\frac{f'(b)-f'(a)}{b-a}$$

Assuming I am even going the right direction with this, I do not know how to show that $f''(0)=0$ and that $f''$ changes sign at $0$. Most of what I am reading speaks in regards to a $\delta$ neighborhood of $0$ where I may be able to prove a sign change.

Any helpful hints or guidance is greatly appreciated. Preferably more leaning towards hints and NOT full blown spoilers on this question. :)

**EDIT:**

$f''$ is not known to be differentiable, $f'$ is known to be differentiable and we are applying the mean value theorem to it.

Comment: It is not clear to me why you say: "So, $-f''$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and $f''$ is differentiable on $(a,b)$"

Comment: You are not given that $f''$ is differentiable. The best you can do is that either $f''$ is increasing or $f''$ is decreasing on the neighborhood of $0$.

Comment: @Daniel From the question it states that $f''$ is continuous on the open interval containing 0, choose $2$ arbitrary values and now you have a closed interval of continuity

Comment: @UmbertoP. I am givin that that $f''$ is $1-1$ which implies that $f'''$ is either greater or less than $0$ for all values in that interval, which implies differentiability.

Comment: You are not given that $f''$ is differentiable.

Comment: @NickPavini In order to talk about $f'''$ you need $f''$ to be differentiable in a first place

Comment: @Daniel read the comment I just left for Umberto

Comment: @NickPavini I can think on many non-differentiable functions that are both increasing and continuous

Comment: In your edit you are asserting something that is simply not true. The burden of proof is on you, not the answerer.

Comment: @Daniel increasing does not mean $1-1$, if you need to you can look up the proof for the relationship of $1-1$ and the derivative always being positive or negative you can find a good proof on wikipedia or a hundred other sources.

Comment: How does a one to one function imply differentiability?

Comment: @NickPavini I have not made myself clear. My point is that your statement  "$f'''$  is either greater or less than $0$ for all values in that interval, which implies differentiability" is not correct, since in order to talk about $f'''$ you need to know it exists at first in order to refer to it.

Comment: @Daniel Maybe I am not being clear, we do know that, and I am about to edit with a link. If you can not see it then please feel free to not worry about this question it may be above your head.

Comment: @Te55eract $1-1$ implies differentiability if and only if it is paired wit the fact that the function is continuous. $1-1$ implies increasing or decreasing , and continuity implies that all values satisfy the domain. If a function is decreasing or increasing across its whole domain such that no $2$ points are equal, then $f'$ of that function is less than or greater than 0, for all $x$ in that domain. Let $f''$ be said function ad we apply the implications to $f'''$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $f''$ is continuous and injective it is either increasing or decreasing.

Consider a sequence of points $x_k \searrow 0$. For each $k$ there exists $y_k \in (0,x_k)$ satisfying $$f''(y_k) = \frac{f'(x_k) - f'(0)}{x_k - 0} = \frac{f'(x_k)}{x_k} > 0.$$

Since $f''$ is continuous you can then show $f''(0) \ge 0$. Since $f''$ attains positive values along a sequence decreasing to $0$, it follows that $f''$ cannot be decreasing - it is thus increasing.

Can you proceed from there?

Comment: I think so, I now need to show from the other side? I.e. $y_k \in (x_k,0)$? Since the interval is from both sides? As well as that means my assumption is correct?

Comment: What assumption?

Comment: That $f''$ is differentiable and therefore we can use the Mean Value Theorem. BTW Thank you.

Comment: Also, yes, if you work from the left you can find that $f''(0) \le 0$ and all sorts of nice things about $f''$.

Comment: As the commenters, myself included, pointed out to you many times already, $f''$ is **not differentiable**.

Comment: ?? You are using the mean value theorem in your solution? As well as for you to say that $f''(0)\ge 0$ is wrong because then $f''(0) would not be an inflection point. Therefore your answer is incorrect.

Comment: I don't understand the objection.

Comment: In order for something to be an inflection point, $f''(x)=0$ is this not true? The whole question is to show that there is a point of inflection at $x=0$. As well as for you to use the formula you did with any certainty, the conditions of the mean value theorem must have been met

Comment: Everything you just said is true. I still don't understand the objection.

Comment: The objection is that you cannot use the formula you did unless you agree with the differentiablilty of $f''$. As well as you said that $f''(0)\not=0$ implying $f''(0)$ is not a point of inflection

Comment: I am not going to respond further except to say $f''(0) \ge 0$ absolutely does not mean $f''(0) \not= 0$, and in no way was $f''$ required to be differentiable.

Comment: Ok I am not trying to argue here, this is all for my greater understanding, but why were you able to use the MVT then? The whole reason I tried to relate differentiabiIity is so I can use that formula. I can complete the proof, I understand how to use the fact that $f''$ is pos. or $0$ on one side and neg. or $0$ on the other, I get that.

Comment: Sorry for the hardhead lol I see what is going on thank you:)

Answer (score 1):

Let's work in an interval $(-c,c)$ where $f''$ is $1$-$1$ and continuous.

If $d\in(0,c)$, you have
$$
f''(y_+)=\frac{f'(d)-f(0)}{d-0}=\frac{f'(d)}{d}>0
$$
for some $y_+\in(0,d)$. Similarly you have
$$
f''(y_-)=\frac{f'(-d)-f(0)}{-d-0}=\frac{f'(-d)}{-d}<0
$$
for some $y_-\in(-d,0)$. By continuity of $f''$, there is $\xi\in(y_-,y_+)\subset(-d,d)$ such that $f''(\xi)=0$. By injectivity, $\xi$ is uniquely determined and belongs to $(-d,d)$, for every $0<d<c$.

> Therefore $\xi=0$.

Now finish up

> by observing that $f''(x)<0$ for $-c<x<0$ and $f''(x)>0$ for $0<x<c$.

Comment: Im not understanding why we can use the formula in the mean value theorem if $f"$ is not known to be differentiable? I dont mean to be difficult.

Comment: @NickPavini It is $f'$ that's differentiable, so we *can* apply the mean value to it.

Comment: Thank you! So i was doing it right just with the wrong logic:) that makes so much sense

Answer (score 1):

Let's first prove that $f''(0) = 0$. Clearly if $f''(0) > 0$ then $f'$ is strictly increasing at $0$ and since $f'(0) = 0$ the derivative $f'(x)$ must be negative for all sufficiently small negative values of $x$. This contradicts that $f'(x) > 0$ for all $x \neq 0$. Similarly we can show that $f''(0)$ can not be negative.

Apart from this we must prove that there is some interval $[-h, h]$ around $0$ such that $f'$ is decreasing in $[-h, 0]$ and increasing in $[0, h]$. We are given that $f''$ is continuous and one-one on some interval containing $0$. We can take $h$ small enough so that $f''$ is continuous and one-one on $[-h, h]$. Then $f''$ is monotone (you should try to prove that *continuous one-one functions are strictly monotone*). Since $f''(0) = 0$ it follows that $f''(x) < 0$ for all $x \in [-h, 0)$ and $f''(x) > 0$ for all $x \in (0, h]$. This means that $f'$ is strictly decreasing in $[-h, 0]$ and strictly increasing in $[0, h]$ and therefore $f$ has an inflection point at $0$.